# ant <scp> support for ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, ant

I have an existing build.properties file that uses scp like this:

```
<scp todir="${linux.user}@${linux.site}:@{todir}" keyfile="${ssh.keyfile}" passphrase="${ssh.passphrase}" trust="yes" verbose="@{verbose}">
   <filestocopy />
</scp>
```

The documentation for that command is here:
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html

I would like to move to ssh-agent and eliminate the passphrase.  Some people who are using this have configured their ssh to NOT use passwords and leave passphrase blank.

One alternative is to use http://www.jcraft.com/jsch-agent-proxy/ , but I found this 1.5 year old question that says it is not supported yet:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684309/can-ant-using-ssh-encrypted-private-key-from-pageant

This is used in many ant scripts so I need a plan that would allow me to use ssh-agent while still allowing others to continue with their method.

I am on Windows 7 trying to scp files to Linux.  I have a Pageant compatible ssh-agent: KeePass2/KeeAgent.

Answer (score 2):

Not *exactly* what you asked for, but I've solved my similar problem (within Maven Antrun plugin on OS X) by using the [exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) instead. So you might use, for example, something like this to replace what you have:

```
<exec executable="pscp">
   <arg value="dirtocopy"/>
   <arg value="-r"/>
   <arg value="-i"/>
   <arg value="${ssh.keyfile}"/>
   <arg value="${linux.user}@${linux.site}:@{todir}"/>
</exec>
```

It's not ideal of course. For cross-platform support you'd require everyone to have an SCP implementation already installed, and you'd need conditionals to choose between `scp` on *nix and `pscp` or whatever on Windows.

However it has some advantages – `ssh-agent` integration just works (as per your original request), and you probably don't need the `-i` argument I've included for completeness.

**Caveat**: I haven't actually tested this with the PuTTY suite or on Windows